# Hitting the CMS Limits of Portable Code

Tags: c, mainframe

I wrote this arbitrary precision arithmetic utility on BSD in my postgraduate days, then after graduating ported it to DOS using TurboC. Was proud that it would do the same thing with 16bit word limits as it had done with 32. Later got a staff account for a university CMS IBM mainframe and started to port it there but had all sorts of compiler/runtime failures until a seasoned IBMer advised I change my function call symbols. "The function call names are clashing with your VM name space" I was told, so rename them or prefix them with an underscore or something else. The VM "D:" drive, its "filenames", and the "executive text" files all lived in the same flat namespace.

That was the end of portability to CMS, sadly, after I had carefully handled all the ASCII / EBCDIC mappings for the interpreter's scanner.

Is CMS still alive and well, and is it still illegal to have a "C" function name identical to a file name?

Comment: PS: For non-insiders, CMS stood for Conversational Mode System, an interactive version of IBM's time share environments that was to be a response to DEC's interactive command line interface.

Comment: Weird. It seems like a simple extension to "auto-prefix" application ID's, thus putting them into their own "namespace", would be an essential addition.

Comment: I think it was more pervasive than just the main entry point. The same namespace issue applied with relocatable "subroutines". I remember my application had modules funcN,c which defined function funcN(), and I had to change those names too.

Comment: There are VM/CMS C compilers that claim ANSI C conformance, so presumably they don't have this problem.

Comment: Good to know. At the time K&R was _the_ standard and goodness knows how compilers were built in non-native settings. @Slow's note above also reminds me that Fortran was native on that platform and when ported to a C-native environment such as BSD UNIX the library references of say function call funcN() of f77 prepended a '_' to the name into _funcN() in "C" and the linker was happy. But the opposite direction albeit rare, cannot have been that straight forward.

Comment: @MKhomo Not "Conversational Mode System", **[Conversational Monitor System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversational_Monitor_System)**

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: On reading the link @manassehkatz provided I should also correct my first comment about a "response to DEC's terminal processors". The proper chronology is the evolution of mainframe peripheral processing heavily invested into by CMS to that spin-off company that came up with "Peripheral Data Processors", better known as DEC PDP's and their (dumb in IBM-speak) virtual terminals VTXXX

Comment: When was this? 1990s? There were some issues back then.

The current C compiler on CMS should not be an issue. Do you still have the code? I may be able to get access to a CMS system to compile.

Comment: 1989 to be exact, and it was a University of Illinois Chicago mainframe. We did get it to compile, but the source was no longer recognizable as a 'port' of the original. And, it was strictly K&R, with no function signature enforcement, et cetra. The only thing it did was provide the scanner upstream code base with EBCDIC awareness.

Comment: So long as I do not need to rewrite to contemporary standards, I can dig up something close to the version I 'ported' to the mainframe. At the time my thinking was it could serve as an arithmetic precision utility that numeric programs could link to. I recall having spoken to someone at Argonne Lab and the intention was to see how it ran in a Cray, but all that is more or less moot - thirty years later - with handhelds matching the supercomputers of that era.

Comment: @ zarchasmpgmr I've been trying to put that utility on GitHub and I have a bit of a learning curve to overcome before I can succeed. I'll tell you when its uploaded successfully.

Comment: @ zarchasmpgmr: OK, I think it is available there now. under the repository https://github.com/mtkAtGH/apax.git

Comment: @MKhomo You might want to use [grip](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip) to preview and experiment with your `README.md` before committing it. Currently, it's one big block of text because Markdown rewraps everything into one paragraph unless you separate with blank lines (ie. two consecutive newlines). Also, you might want to use use \`backticks\` to put things like `libapa.a` and `NULL` in `<code>` formatting.

Comment: Plenty learning curve. I'll try and clean it up eventually.

Comment: @MKhomo Fair enough. One quick piece of advice is that, if you name it `README` or `README.txt` instead of `README.md`, it'll be rendered verbatim. GitHub supports a [bunch](https://github.com/github/markup/blob/master/README.md#markups) of different formats for any file it renders like that.

Comment: Thanks. I started with your suggestion for back quotes and extra returns, and that seems to have helped a lot. Also explained the utility a bit more.

Comment: @MKhomo Happy to help. For more, [this page](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax) does a really nice job of introducing the common subset of all Markdown dialects. [GitHub's guide](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) covers fancier things like code blocks with syntax highlighting or linking to repositories, issue tracker entries, or commits.

Comment: CMS and CP are both very much alive in the current zVM OS. We used it within IBM itself sometime in the previous decade to virtualise multiple z/OS environments.

Comment: @paxdiablo, good to hear. Someone earlier indicated C language namename spaces on CMS now nest with no clashes beween file names and executive function names. You'll see above I uploaded an old snapshot of the source at github to verify that. Its all pristine K&R C.